# Plesk default page while Wordpress is installed in httpdocs

Tags: wordpress, plesk

The default plesk page displays while there is a Wordpress installation in httpdocs. What do I change to display the Wordpress installation? The page came out of nowhere, we made no changes to the website.

Comment: I just managed to read your wp-config.php, please be aware you should change database passwords, user passwords, keys and salts. I also think you're not providing enough information for people to help you. Including that it's a multisite.(my personal preference is not making multisites, just install it a few times more)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file named `welcome.php` or something like that in the `httpdocs` folder or try to reinstall `WordPress` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's an order of loading files from the `httpdocs`, and usually `index.html` is before `index.php` - so if there's an `index.html` AND an `index.php` in the folder, then `index.html` is loaded before `index.php`.

So, if you have `index.html` in your folder try deleting that. (Or delete everything that's not Wordpress.)

Or you could just delete everything in that folder and reinstall WordPress.